# How by using python I can open cmd in the path i need and run a command

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd

I have 2 folders in my directory: time0 and time1. 
I need to write a script in python what will have an endless loop- so that every 10 min I'm entering a different folder (time0/1) using cmd and writing in the cmd a command ("terraform init")

I was able to open the cmd using os.system("start cmd") but I cant go forther to the folder I need and write the "init" function.

any ideas?

Comment: there is a wrapper in python to use terraform, maybe it can be handy for what you need to perform https://github.com/beelit94/python-terraform

Comment: i'm less worried about the init commend.. i tried everything and i cant find the way to open cmd in the path i want and write a command. it always open the cmd in the default path and does nothing

Comment: A directory can be specified on the `START` command. Use `START /?` for more information. Yes, the `subprocess` module would be more capable than os.system().

Comment: `subprocess` *directly supports* passing the directory to run in out-of-band; see the `cwd` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the [Subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: I agree that `subprocess` is the right thing, but generally speaking, an answer should be meatier than this: A good StackOverflow answer stands on its own, ie. is still useful even if all links contained therein break. Showing an example of `subprocess` usage that opens a program in a different (specified) directory would be a good place to start.